# iphone, need to put many text boxes on the view, how to scroll down to view more content?

Tags: iphone

iphone, need to put many text boxes on the view, how to scroll down to view more content? I actually put buttons and labels on the ScrollView, but the scrolling doesn't work. Do I need to write any code for that, any example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `contentSize` property of the `UIScrollView` to something bigger than its frame size.

```
[aScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
```

Comment: Whenever you know how big the contentSize should be

Comment: the only way it worked for me was this `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [scrolltweets setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
}` any other time seems to be too early to set the size